# Apache Benchmark

Tags: apache-2.2

I want to test my applocation by using APACHE BENCHMARk.
I got this command.
If I execute this command,it displays  ab: command not found
But where I can Execute this command,
ab -n 1000 -c 5 http://202.54.200.1/snkpage.html

Comment: The command might be called `ab2` or then you don't have Apache Benchmark installed at all. I don't currently have my Mind Reader Expansion Pack docked to my head so you need to rephrase your question quite a bit.

Comment: As @Janne said you should rephrase your question to include more details. Which Linux Distribution are you using, which version of it? Did you compile Apache yourself or did you use a binary distribution for your system ?

Comment: My guess is the OP is trying to run that command from his workstation (which may not be Linux, or may not have Apache installed) to test a website hosted somewhere else (which is the best way to do it).

Comment: If you are using ubuntu then you can follow this link:

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/66606/what-package-includes-ab-the-apache-server-benchmarking-tool-in-ubuntu][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/66606/what-package-includes-ab-the-apache-server-benchmarking-tool-in-ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

You run `ab` from a machine / account which has it installed.  It's usually part of the Apache2 package in various Linux distributions, or you can download / compile it yourself.  You don't tell us anything about your setup though so it's not possible to answer in more detail.